# yii2 boostrap 5 and modal

Tags: yii2, bootstrap5-modal

Edit:
I discovered that if i do a clean install, the modal works, and it's after adding hail812/yii2-adminlte3 that the modal system won't work anymore... but i don't find what create this,

original:

little question, does any of you use yii/boostrap5/modal and succeed to render ajax form in a modal ? Because my code used with the older bootstrap won't work.. and i don't find how the new yii/bootstrap5/modal works...

here is my code

```
<?php
 yii\bootstrap5\Modal::begin([
  'id' => 'modal',
  'size' => 'modal-lg',
   //keeps from closing modal with esc key or by clicking out of the modal.
   // user must click cancel or X to close
  'clientOptions' => ['backdrop' => 'static', 'keyboard' => TRUE]
  ]);
  echo '<div id="modalContent"></div>';
  yii\bootstrap5\Modal::end();
?>

<?php
  $this->registerJs( <<< EOT_JS_CODE
  $(function(){
  // changed id to class
  $('.modalButton').click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
      $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
        $('#modal').modal('show').find('#modalContent').html(data)
     });
     document.getElementById('modalHeader').innerHTML = '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button><h4>' +     $(this).attr('title') + '</h4>';
   return false;
  });
});
EOT_JS_CODE

);
?>
```

the link i use to open the modal:

```
  <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Ajouter'), ['create-categorie'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success modalButton','title'=>'Nouvelle catégorie']) ?>
```

And my code in my controller

```
  public function actionCreateCategorie()
{
  $model = new Categorie();
  if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
      $model->created_at = strtotime('now');
      $model->updated_at = strtotime('now');
      if( $model->save()){
        return 'success';
      }else{
        return 'error';
      }
  }

  return $this->renderAjax('create-categorie', [
      'model' => $model,
  ],false, true);
}
```

my console with a strange error i don't get
[image]

Comment: Yes, i have used and its working for me. What is the issue that you find, can you please add your console as well?

Comment: thank you for your answer @FahadAli - i took my code from my previous app, and it works in the old one, but when i try to open my form (renderAjax in controller) in the modal in the new app, nope, it goes directly to the form, without the template as it's renderAjax, but it does not work.  What do you mean by my console ?

Comment: @FahadAli hey, do you succeed to renderAjax a form ? i will update my post to add my controller function and my href link

Comment: @FahadAli is you see my picture with my console, you'll see a "click me" button, this one load the modal, but nothing inside, and if i click on my green buttons, it goes to the form, and load a new page, no loading form in the modal

Comment: I have copy/pasted all your code and its works fine here. so if you can add all your code for views files along with controller code, because its hard to understand the reason behind the error just by seeing half of snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your helps. Something wasn't right with my installation. I began with a new fresh install, then reused my code, and everything is fine then.

Kind regards